# Nested list in excel

Tags: excel, list, nested

I'm not even sure how to ask this.

I have a database, where each row is a person. Columns are contact info, phone, etc. One column is 'date visited'. There can be multiple dates visited for each person. I don't want to use a comma or stack them all in one field.

Is there a way to have a 'nested' list (not a drop-down menu - just a list of visited dates for each person), such that one person still only consumes one single row?

Comment: actuallly not really. Using separators would be the easiest way to handle this or several columns. What would you want to do with the data?

Comment: JMax's question is a good one. One option you can look at is rows grouping, so you could have multiple rows and the possibility to collapse / expand them as you need.

Comment: Only reason is if I wanted to create a formula to easily count the number of visited dates; I assume it would be more difficult if they are all packed into the same cell. It also looks ugly that way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

To accomplish this give each person an ID that is unique and won't change.
Then on a separate sheet, store the ID and date.

main sheet ( ID, Name, Contact Info, phone, ect)
second sheet ( ID, date visited)

In database theory this is called a 'one to many' relationship, and what i'm describing is called 'normalizing your dataset'.

In Excel you can now use formulas to manipulate the data however you need to or can imagine after you split this apart.

As you mentioned in comment, counting all visited dates for a user.
On the main sheet to the right you could use:

```
=countif(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1)
```

This would Count all of the ID's in the second sheet that match the current row's ID on your main sheet.

**Notes about using one cell:**

Storing all the dates in one cell will eventually max it out, and will make it hard ot view/search as it grows so i highly advise against this approach.

If however you insist on keeping the dates in there, you could count the visits by counting the total number of comma's + 1 liek this `=(LEN(G1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G1,",","")))+1` This formula takes the length of all the dates, and the length of dates with commas removed and subtracts them to get a number of occurrences.

**Notes about using multiple columns:**

This approach has the same idea as the one I suggested, where we are associating a number of dates with the row's identity of a person. However, there are a few key limitations and drawbacks.

The main difference is that when we abstract the dates by transposing them to extend vertically we can manipulate them easier, and make a list of 20 dates for one person much easier to read. By transposing the dates vertically in the second sheet instead of using this approach we also gain the ability to use Excel's built in filter. Just storing large amounts of data is useless by itself. While storing it in a way that you can view and manipulate easy makes everything much more *powerful*.

Comment: @user1566200 if this solved your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer with a ✔